# Function TO_DAYS mysql on SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

How can this mysql syntax running on SQL server:

```
SELECT TO_DAYS('2013-04-14')
```

how `TO_DAYS` function can running on SQL Server?

Thanks..

Finally, I use

```
SELECT CAST(CAST('2013-04-14' as datetime) as integer)
```

Thanks for your answer before

Comment: I don't know if there's a built in function in mssql server 'cause first date is gregorian `'1/1/1753'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit: I read the original question as TO_DATE, modified for TO_DAYS

I see TO_DAYS function in MySQL gives the number of days between year 0 and the date parameter.

A basic equivalent in SQL Server is to use DateDiff
e.g.

```
select Datediff(d,'1900-01-01', '2013-04-14')
```

Comment: yes you are right...but, how can you put this date 1900-01-01? 


i was try but the result is different.

in mysql 735337 and in SQL server 41376. thanks for the fast respond

Comment: I use 
SELECT CAST(CAST('2013-04-14' as datetime) as integer)

Thanks for your answer before.

Comment: In your example, MySQL is using the year 0 and comparing it to 2013 and coming up with 735337 days. In SQL Server, the datetime datatype only extends to the year 1753. If you read the history of calendars, you will find that nobody agrees exactly how many days since the year 0, so MySQL is making some bad assumptions. You need to explain to us why you need the number of days since 0, because the answer to that question is ambiguous. I suggest to you that you can change the logic of your query to work with a well defined date. In SQL server, day 1 is 1900-01-01. In UNIX it is 1970-01-01

Comment: If you are stuck with your application code, you could always just add 693961 ( days diff between SQL Server day 0 and MySQL day 0) but this is a magic number and magic numbers are always a bad idea. Explain to us the context of your query

Comment: thank you so much, i use to_days only to calculate range between two date, is about overdue... something like this, 
<pre>SUM(CASE WHEN ((CAST(CAST('2013-04-30' as datetime) as integer)) - (CAST(CAST((CASE WHEN trans.type in(20,21) THEN trans.due_date ELSE
trans.tran_date END) as datetime) as integer)) >=30) THEN  (trans.ov_amount + trans.ov_gst + trans.ov_discount) ELSE 0 END) as overdue1</pre>
and its,work thank...

Comment: Idont need to count since the year 0, i just need to calculate about two date but, im stuck and only knew about TO_DAYS, if i used datediff i cant put in the "IF" syntax on the first date...so i try to use CAST (as your answer before) and running well.

Comment: Ah good. That's a much better way to do it. Just be careful with DateDiff, because it counts boundaries (if you are counting days, the boundary is midnight - it doesn't count 24 hour intervals). I.E. if you measure from 2013-04-26 23:59 until 2013-04-27 00:01 in days it will tell you 1 day, even though this is only 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Given that there isn't a year 0 in our calendar, I'd argue that the `TO_DAYS` function is poorly defined.

But assuming that you're using SQL Server 2008 or later, the following should work:

```
select 366+DATEDIFF(day,'00010101','20130414')
```

There's no avoiding the "fudge" factor, since SQL Server doesn't accept dates from the year 0 as valid.